# How do I prevent unauthorized users from accessing MongoDB which is in docker container?

Tags: mongodb, docker, authentication, docker-compose

MongoDB in the docker container and the container was powered by docker-compose.yml file.

There are version informations.

- MongoDB version: 6.0.5
- Mongosh version: 1.8.0
- Docker Version: 23.0.1

And this is my docker-compose.yml.

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    container_name: mongodb
    ports:
       - "<ex port>:<in port>"
    command: [--auth]
    environment:
       MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: "<Admin>"
       MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: "<AdminPassword>"
       MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: "admin"
    volumes:
       - ./data/mongodb:/data/db
```

I created an administrator account and a user with write/read permissions, and I checked that both accounts get db access normally.

**However, it is still possible to access db without account, and even create a new db.** Please refer to [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI8DC.png).

**I want to make it impossible to access mongodb without account information.**
What's the problem I'm missing?

I thought there was an account other than the one I created, so I accessed it with an administrator account and looked at the list of users. However, there were no other accounts than the 2 accounts I created (administrator, user with read/write permission).

I added `command: [--auth]` in the docker-compose.yml file. I expected this setting to prevent unauthorized users from accessing the db, but it wasn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's normal. You can connect (almost) anytime to a MongoDB without credentials.

However, without authentication you can run only harmless commands like `db.help()`, `db.getMongo()`, `db.listCommands()`. All other commands will fail with error "Authentication required"

Comment: Thank you for stopping me from digging further into this!